# What does the space of holomorphic maps look like inside the space of equivariant maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Consider a map from a closed topological surface $S$ into, for example, a fixed compact complex hyperbolic manifold.

For each point in the Teichmuller space of $S$ this map is homotopic to a unique harmonic map. Sometimes, but often not, this harmonic map is actually holomorphic.

What does the locus in Teichmuller space look like where this map is holomorphic?

This is intended to be an open ended question, but perhaps some first questions are whether the image of the locus is connected in moduli space, whether the locus is a complex manifold, whether the dimension can be bounded, ....

Note that if the target manifold is complex hyperbolic of dimension 1 then it is just a Riemann surface. I am interested in both this 1 dimensional case and the higher dimension case.

Comment: This is a good question, but very little is known about it (even nonemptyness is quite hard and this is the most primitive of all topological invariants of a space). I will add what I know about related questions when I have more time.